# Transforming float pandas column to int gives me -2147483648 (platform-specific error)

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have a large number with decimals I want to transform to `int`, but I keep getting `-2147483648`

Please, try:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
a.loc[0] = 31062000999100.0000000
```

Now `a.dtypes` gives me a  `float`

`a = a.astype(str)` gives me an object `31062000999100.0`
And `a = a.astype('int')` gives me `-2147483648`. Using `astype(int)`yields the same result.

I know float objects are approximations, so I also tried `round(a)`, but the results kept being `-2147483648`. `a = a.astype('int').astype('str')` also did not work.

p.s. This runs in `Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]` and `pandas 0.22.0` That means Microsoft 10 x64

p.s.2 This has been proved to be platform-specific (Windows) not happening on Linux Ubuntu nor Mint. @Roberto. Also a problen in. Pyandroid...

Comment: That's the largest (magnitude) signed 32 bit integer

Comment: 31062000999100 is too big to be treated as an integer. You've got an overflow.

Comment: Try `.astype('int64')`

Comment: `astype('int64')` worked, so simple, so much time. Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error in Python 3. Is this a Python 2 "issue" by chance?

Comment: No. It is python3. Although my system is x64 like I said, it seems pandas is using int32 by default. Using @ALollz suggestion worked.

Comment: Hmm I see... Just for comparison I have Anaconda Python 3.6.4 (64-bit) and Pandas 0.22.0, and they seem to work ok with that number. Edit: on Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: @Roberto Me too (see the edit). My co-developer also used Linux and did not catch this.

Comment: Hi you can set a shortest datatype by using something like this [Example of low memory and shortest datatype](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168746/apply-the-smallest-possible-datatype-for-each-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-re)

Comment: @BFurtado yes you're right, I can confirm that it's platform-specific too. While on Linux I couldn't replicate the issue, on Windows 10 64-bit,  Anaconda Python 3.6.4 and Pandas 0.22.0 I do get the bug.